# how to remove this artifact (screenshot) when adjusting mean crease

Tags: subdivision-surface

Mesh with subdiv: how to remove this artifact when adjusting mean crease but keep the existing mesh shape?

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w2B0rnAYdgd8S2SZndqoy7zUiTBIU18C/view?usp=drive_link)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given your curent topology, you can either crease the whole angle loops, or add support loops:

[image]

You can also modify the topology and make the angles like this:

[image]

Edit: You can't select the edge loops in your model because you beveled the angles, so the selection stops. Here is how to fix it

[image]

Comment: thank you! can I ask you to apply this to the example from my .blend file? I can not: https://i.imgur.com/Jhhy076.mp4

Comment: @blenduser I updated the answer

Comment: >>@blenduser I updated the answer 

---------------------------------------------

in the title of the message I asked not to affect the shape of the object. Just remove the highlighted artifacts. Mesh should remain exactly as it is, without any changes

Comment: thanks, your second example suits me - with a different topology
https://i.imgur.com/HwRKyh7.png